# How to revoke "Always allow" privileges from an application?

Tags: terminal, command-line, security, permission, keychain

The application I have in mind is the `security` command line tool bundled with Macos. The `man` page describes it as:

```
security -- Command line interface to keychains and Security framework
```

---

At some point recently I wanted to get a password from my keychain using the command-line. Which is done using the following command:

```
matt@laptop ~ $ security find-generic-password -a 'foobar'
```

The first time I ran it I saw the usual *Always Allow*, *Deny*, and *Allow* dialogue. I (foolishly) picked *Always Allow* and now I can't find how/where to undo that.

I've looked using Keychain Access to see if the `security` tool appears there but it doesn't. The closest thing I could find was an entry for `CommCenter` but it was last modified before I ever used the `security` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch the Keychain Access Utility and find the entry you used that password:

- Right click it to bring up its info window
- Click the Access Control Tab and there you will see a list of applications that have "Always allow access" enabled
- Highlight the application in the list that you want remove and click the `[-]` button to remove it from Always allowed access.

[image: Chrome Safe Storage configuration dialogue, Access Control tab]

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out which entry has been added as a result of this particular _Always Allow_. Do you have any idea how I might track it down in this case?

Comment: Well, its a password so make sure you're only looking at the Passwords as selected in the Navigation bar. I see modification dates when I view the list of password this way- do any of the modification dates you see match the day you made your terminal change?